# How can I shut down an included launch file?

Tags: ros2, launch-file

Hello I need assistance on a specific issue, that I can't find a solution.

**Required Info:**
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
Installation type: binaries
Version: ROS2 Humble

**Context:**
I have a launch file that manage several included launch file.
In every included launch file, there is several lifecycle node and a manager node.
And they can have other included launch file within them

When the lifecycle nodes end their work, I want to shutdown the included launch file and    all the children included launch file.

What I tried to do is:

```py
event_handlers.append( 
               RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=manager_node,
                on_exit=EmitEvent(event=Shutdown()),
                          )
              )
              )
```

**Expected behavior**
The event *Shutdown()* destroy the launch file and all its children included launch file

**Actual behavior**
Everything is killed event the parent launch file.

How Can I kill one child launch file and all its children without killing the parent one ?

Best regards,

Alexis